# When is it necessary to initialize or reset all tags using a wildcard * at the beginning of external CSS style?

Tags: html, css

When is it necessary to use a wildcard * to reset or initialize all tags at the beginning of a CSS document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is never *necessary*, some people just prefer to start from a known baseline rather then the various different browser defaults.

Slapping it in a wildcard isn't really recommended though as it can have unwanted effects on certain elements (such as form controls). This has resulted in slightly more complex resets such as [Eric's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Yahoo!'s](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Answer (score 1):

The reset files David referres to are really helpful to clean up the default markup of the different browsers, but keep in mind that you must hard-style a lot of elements. Lists, headers and other elements look really ugly without any kind of markup. I usually have on top of my stylesheet a couple of rules to rewrite some basic markup that every website uses anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good discussion of resets [here](http://www.cssbakery.com/2009/02/css-resets.html).